Emulating port redirection (port 53) without root
How to emulate binary program that reading port 53 will be redirected to another port such as port 10053.
So the binary program still sees it as 53 but the actual port at top layer will be redirected to 10053.
I'm using android non-root, the binary program is reading port 53 which it doesn't have DNS server installed and not permitted to listen such port (port 0-1023 is not allowed for non-root user)
Is there any idea? Can proot handle that? Or is there another approach?
Specifically, the binary program I mean is cloudflared. I downloaded cloudflared for aarch64 instead of from termux repository because cloudflared at termux is obselete, (it was working fine previously).
That downloaded binary is trying to read port 53 for local dns server which it's not possible in android non root.
Perhaps proot can do that?

This seems like an XY problem. You're asking about how to make cloudflared work a certain way, rather than explaining what you want to achieve and why you think that program will help. Is there a reason you can't use WARP?

@Walf correct! I can't use WARP since I'm currently in another VPN service (V2rayNG). Enabling both VPN service which are WARP and V2rayNG is not possible.

Perhaps you can request that DNS servers be customisable, as they are in DNS66 and Daedalus, over at their issue tracker.

Try Daedalus, which uses Android's non-root proxy system.
This enables it to intercept DNS requests to the regular port 53, and forward them to the server you want to use, and use non-standard ports.
I assume what you want here is something like:
cloudflared proxy-dns --address 127.0.0.1 --port 50053

Then add a DNS server to Daedalus with the same address and port, and press its Activate button to use the proxy.
You may have to disable the system Private DNS setting.

That app will using VPN service while I already had another VPN service enabled.
